Azure DevOps Snowflake Automation
I want to trigger an Azure DevOps (ADO) pipeline based off of the timestamp of data in Snowflake.
If there is new data, trigger ADO pipeline, else keep monitoring until 12pm and if there is still no new data then trigger the pipeline anyways.
I have a list of dependencies (Snowflake tables) which I want to monitor. When the updated date = today, i.e. there is new data, the condition to trigger the ADO pipeline is met.
So, how can I trigger my pipeline based off of the timestamp in dependant tables and if no new data is present by 12pm, how can I trigger my build to run anyways?


I want to trigger an Azure DevOps (ADO) pipeline based off of the timestamp of data in Snowflake.

Azure DevOps pipeline can be used for CI-CD and can also be triggered by external services. However, the triggering behavior should be issued by the external service. Snowflake should provide features for monitoring data and sending "events" to the outside service. However, based on my knowledge, Snowflake currently has no such feature.
Based on the current situation, I would suggest you create a function app to periodically check your Snowflake and trigger Azure DevOps pipeline using REST API.

It only occurred the me after posting the question, but I figured out a solution. Yes I was always planning to use the rest API, or azure cli to trigger my ado pipeline. I have a watcher pipeline monitoring snowflake, and when conditions are met I run a task to trigger the main pipeline. The issue was with having that pipeline run at 12pm, even if there was no new data. I realise I can just check $[pipeline.startTime] at the beginning of the watcher pipeline, if after 12pm then trigger main pipeline. Thanks for the help anyways !
